# SQL Server : get hour from datetime and then change it

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, hour

I have been trying this for a while and so far research has not gotten me far other than I need to use something called `DATEPART` (I have no idea how to use this). My SQL Server is not the greatest.

I have `declare @DueDate datetime` and through a cursor `@DueDate` will always been the current row's `DueDate` (`datetime`) column. This so far works perfectly without issue.

Now what I am trying to do is get the hour out of `@DueDate`, check to see if it is 0, and if the hour is 0, set the `@DueDate` hour to midnight and then update the rows DueDate column with this `@DueDate` variable.

As stated above I have the cursor and variables all working, I just don't know how to get the hour from `@DueDate`, check what that hour value is, and update the @DueDate variable so its hour is now midnight. I know how the update the table, that is the easy part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does exactly what you want without using the cursor.

```
UPDATE [MyTable]
SET DueDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, DueDate) -- add one day (set to midnight)
WHERE DATEPART(hh, DueDate) = 0 -- do this for dates where hour is zero (midnight)
```

Note that you should avoid using cursors where possible. SQL development requires a different way of thinking. Don't think about iterations, think atomic. You can do most things in a single statement (one statement can be very long if complicated enough).

Comment: That increased the day by 1 and did not work but I modified the code to work, set duedate = dateadd(hh, 1, duedate).

Comment: @LandinMartens. So you're taking all dates that are midnight, and setting them to 1am. That's not what you asked for, but glad I could help!